# Making iframe show inline

Tags: html, css, iframe, inline

I have this code here:
http://html.cita.illinois.edu/nav/menu/menu-example-vtc.php

It's a navigation bar which I wanna add to show in all my html pages using iframe, the problem that when I add it to my pages it shows above or bottom of the original webpage content like here in this image: [View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qccje.jpg)

I wanna it to be like sidebar not above or under the content but in the left side like it should be.

Comment: Does it have to be a iFrame or can it be a normal div?

Comment: Try setting it in a fixed position nav tag that you style with css.

Comment: Might be easier for us if you make a jsfiddle or jsbin.